# latest typescript breaking changes in lib.dom.ts file

Tags: typescript

In spec.ts For Example: Dom.spec.ts

```
  describe('matchesSelector', () => {
    let result: boolean;
    let matchelement: HTMLElement;
it('Matches for the opera browser', () => {
        matchelement.matches = matchelement.msMatchesSelector = null;
        result = Dom.matches(matchelement, '#match');
        expect(result).toBe(true);
    });
```

when calling msmatchesSelector in matchelement.msMatchesSelector in above code it fetch the specfic type in  lib.dom.ts .
It reproduce the below error when I uprade the typescript version to 3.0

```
spec\dom.spec.ts(304,49): error TS2339: Property 'msMatchesSelector' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

But It works fine in my previous typescript version 2.6.2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a [breaking change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes) between 3.0 and 3.1:

> TypeScript's built-in .d.ts library (lib.d.ts and family) is now partially generated from Web IDL files from the DOM specification. As a result some vendor-specific types have been removed.

The recommendation is to extend the built-in definitions as needed:

> If your run-time guarantees that some of these names are available at run-time (e.g. for an IE-only app), add the declarations locally in your project, e.g.:
>   For Element.msMatchesSelector, add the following to a local dom.ie.d.ts

```
interface Element {
    msMatchesSelector(selectors: string): boolean;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your update.I need to know that in which file I need to add the above interface   `interface Element {
    msMatchesSelector(selectors: string): boolean;
}`

Comment: Can you please explain that what is  local dom in clear.

Comment: @VijayVJ a file in your project ie. a fiel local to your project, nothing special about it

Comment: @ Titian Cernicova-Dragomir Thank you but I need to know whether it is d.ts file or ts file

Comment: @VijayVJ it should be a `.d.ts`

Comment: You mean I have to create one local d.ts file and how can I import d.ts file in my ts file and use the below code `interface Element {
    msMatchesSelector(selectors: string): boolean;
}`

Comment: @VijayVJ yup. it should

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181548/discussion-between-vijay-vj-and-titian-cernicova-dragomir).

Comment: Is it possible to import d.ts file?

Comment: Thank you @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir for the response I found the fix

Answer (score 0):

You can also use these easy codes at top of file

```
interface Element {
   msMatchesSelector: any;
}
```