# Property 'msMatchesSelector' does not exist on type 'Element' in polyfills.ts

Tags: angular, polyfills

I have already tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040790/ts2339-property-msmatchesselector-does-not-exist-on-type-element) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696154/latest-typescript-breaking-changes-in-lib-dom-ts-file) but to no avail. I created a file named `dom.ie.d.ts` in the `src` folder and added the following code:

```
interface Element {
  msMatchesSelector(selectors: string): boolean;
}
```

The error is the following:

> ERROR in src/polyfills.ts:78:51 - error TS2339: Property
> 'msMatchesSelector' does not exist on type 'Element'.

I need to make this work since I am upgrading an old Angular project to the latest version and can not continue upgrading to the next major version until all errors are resolved. Currently the project is set to run on Angular 9.

Answer (score 0):

try this with `export` keyword:

```
    export interface Element {
      msMatchesSelector(selectors: string): boolean;
    }
```

also try importing like

```
    import {Element} from ".. path to dom.ie.d.ts";
```

or

```
    import * as name from ".. path to dom.ie.d.ts";
```

should be accessible as `Element` or `name.Element`

Comment: unfortunately not working :/

Comment: have you tried adding `export interface Element {
      msMatchesSelector(selectors: string): boolean;
    }`  in the same ts file with the component class where you wish to apply this ?